# Error: Failed to list functions for (ProjectName) in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

When I am trying to host my angular application into firebase hosting I got below error even I selected specific project.

`Error: Failed to list functions for (project-name)`

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: firebase login --reauth. run this command

Comment: I have tried but same error

Comment: Can you share complete details of what commands you used and get this? Also is firebase initialized in the directory?

Comment: When I am trying to host my Angular app inside `dist` folder using `firebase deploy --only hosting` command getting the `Error: Failed to list functions for (project-name)`

Comment: So, you build the app and then go into the dist directory to deploy it? 
You need a firebase.json within the folder you are running the command. This might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue by following the below steps.

1. `firebase init hosting`
2. Change the firestore.rules inside `allow read, write: if request.auth !=null;`